# Copy a value from an Array Formula

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I'm trying to create a macro to copy the formula from an array formula, delete the array and then paste that value back into the first cell.

The problem I have is that after selecting the array I can't record F2 and copy contents.
I just end up with whatever was in the paste buffer when I started.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: [**`Evaluate()`**?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa223886(v=office.11).aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you after something like this, where Selection is a cell containing an array formula?

```
theFormula = Selection.Formula
Selection.FormulaArray = ""
Selection = theFormula
```